# Saving a Sql View Error, runs fine but cannot save "incorrect syntax near the keyword declare"

Tags: sql

```
Declare @DaysLeft as INT


;With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT number + 1 as 'CurrentDay'
    FROM   master..spt_values
    WHERE  type='p'
    AND    number < datepart(dd, DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month,
                                          DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),0))))
    AND    datename(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),
                                         number) ) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
)

Select @DaysLeft = (Select COUNT(*) As MyTotal from MyCTE
WHERE CurrentDay >= DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()))

Select @DaysLeft
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a variable in a view.  Remove the variable and rephrase the final select statement.

```
With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT number + 1 as 'CurrentDay'
    FROM   .spt_values
    WHERE  type='p'
    AND    number < datepart(dd, DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month,
                                          DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),0))))
    AND    datename(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),
                                         number) ) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
)

Select COUNT(*) As DaysLeft from MyCTE
WHERE CurrentDay >= DATEPART(DD, GETDATE())
```

Run the modification in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a507/2/0).